# a href not working in facebook canvas url page

Tags: php, facebook, redirect

I am developing a face book application .
 My problem is that , I am trying to redirect to google from the face book app . It is working well from the physical url http://movie.jobslanda.com/fb/ , but will not work from the app url http://apps.facebook.com/moviereviewforyou/. Please help me to find out the problem. And the code in the canvas url page  is just

```
<?php header("Location:http://google.com");
?>
```

Comment: <script>top.location.href="http://google.com";</script> or without top if you wanna stay in the frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use `top.location.href="";`